# Delete shaded rows before save

Tags: vba, ms-word

I've a Word 2013 document with code to shade specified rows based on dropdown selections within the document.

I have it set to delete all shaded rows from the document before printing but I want an additional sub to delete all shaded rows before using the "Save As" function.

Print code that's working:

```vb
Public Sub myApp_DocumentBeforePrint(ByVal Doc As Document, Cancel As Boolean)

    Dim d1 As Document
    Set d1 = ActiveDocument
    
    Dim tbl As Table, r As Row, c As Cell, rng As Range, t As Integer
    Dim i As Integer, n As Integer
    
    'table counter
    t = 1
    
    'cycle through each table
    For Each tbl In d1.Tables
        'row counter
        n = tbl.Rows.Count
        'cycle through the rows in the selected table
        For i = 1 To n Step 1
            'compare pattern fill, select those that are shaded and delete
            If d1.Tables(t).Rows(i).Shading.Texture = wdTextureDarkDiagonalDown Then
                d1.Tables(t).Rows(i).Delete
            End If
        Next
        t = t + 1
    Next
```

SaveAs code that is not working:

```vb
Public Sub myApp_DocumentBeforeSaveAs(ByVal Doc As Document, SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    
    Dim d1 As Document
    Set d1 = ActiveDocument
    
    Dim tbl As Table, r As Row, c As Cell, rng As Range, t As Integer
    Dim i As Integer, n As Integer
    
    'table counter
    t = 1
    
    'cycle through each table
    For Each tbl In d1.Tables
        'row counter
        n = tbl.Rows.Count
        'cycle through the rows in the selected table
        For i = 1 To n Step 1
            'compare pattern fill, select those that are shaded and delete
            If d1.Tables(t).Rows(i).Shading.Texture = wdTextureDarkDiagonalDown Then
                d1.Tables(t).Rows(i).Delete
            End If
        Next
        t = t + 1
    Next
```

I don't get any error codes, it just doesn't do anything to the shaded text.

Comment: First, to make it easier on yourself, I would break out the code to delete shaded rows into a separate `Sub`. Then you can call the sub from anywhere (in this case, both `myApp_DocumentBeforePrint` and `myApp_DocumentBeforeSaveAs`). Have you verified that your code is being executed in the `myApp_DocumentBeforeSaveAs` routine?  Try some `Debug.Print` statements and/or breakpoints and see if you can identify the line(s) that aren't working.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works kind of, but it does generate an error. The issue is on the

```
For i = 1 To n Step 1
```

line of code. To delete rows in a table you need to Step backwards, otherwise when you delete a row, the remaining row count doesn’t equal the number of rows in the table. Your command should be:

```
For i = n to 1 Step -1
```

There is also an unnecessary line of code

```
t = t + 1
```

It’s not creating a problem but it’s unnecessary, at least based on what you have shown us.

Again your code works as long as you correct that Step 1 problem and you know for certain that the row shading is as you have specified being Textured Dark Diagonal Down.